# Error Analysis question regarding ( used to )

Tags: grammar, past-tense, past-vs-present

Yesterday, I had a Grammar exam and I came across this question, I tried to look everywhere on the internet but I couldn't find anything related since "used to" always comes as a habit and followed with a contrast.

The sentence is "He used never to drink so much coffee, before he went to bed." According to the question, it must have two mistakes, so my answer was:
"He used to drink so much coffee, before he goes to bed."

The exam now is nothing I'm worried about, I just want to benefit so I don't make a mistake again.

Comment: I would move *never* forward and drop the comma: *"He never used to drink so much coffee before he went to bed."*

Comment: So is it wrong to say: "I used to drink so much coffee before I go to bed." ?

Comment: There are minor grammatical problems, like consistent tense.... *"before I went to bed"* .............. also the use of *"so much"* is non-colloquial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gary's Student gives you the answer your examiner was almost certainly looking for.

> He never used to drink so much coffee before he went to bed.

The comma in the original marks *before he went to bed* as supplemental and thus an adjunct to the main clause; that implies, absurdly, that for a long time he did not go to bed and it was only when he finally did so that he started drinking coffee.

The placement of *never* in the original marks *used* as an ordinary catenating verb like *want* or *hope*. This is by no means ungrammatical, but today it is so rare that it *almost* has to be regarded as 'obsolete'. In present-day English we treat *used to* as an inseparable fixed phrase, virtually an independent 'modal' verb: *useta*, conjugated only in the past tense.

Comment: I really appreciate your time and thanks for the answer, but is it grammatically wrong to say: "He used to drink so much coffee before he goes to bed."?

Comment: @user265113 *"before he went to bed"*

Comment: @user265113 The tense in the adjunct doesn't matter much, because what you're doing is contrasting his former prebedtime consumption with his present prebedtime consumption; but to 'genericize' the time reference I'd be inclined to say *before **going** to bed*.

Answer (score 0):

Gary's answer is correct.  Your sentence is grammatically incorrect and misleading.  You could however say:  I use to drink a lot of coffee before I went to bed (or before I'd go to bed).